# Blocks of applications disappears

Tags: gnome, interface

I am currently using the latest version of Ubuntu with the classic interface. Every now and then I get "holes" in my running application exposing my background. I don't quite know how I am supposed to describe the problem, so I've uploaded a screenshot of what I mean.

[image]

Comment: Is this with or without desktop effects?

Comment: @WarriorIn64 Without. Ubuntu Classic (no effects).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The uplaoded image is now gone, so can't verify, but it sounds exactly like the problem I have with radeon proprietary driver (fglrx). Are you by any chance using that? A work-around is to switch to another workspace and back. The free driver (xserver-xorg-video-radeon) does not exhibit this problem at all for me, but it lacks some functionality.

Comment: Another solutions is to just take a application window and brush over it, but that is not the point. I will check out the free driver option. Thank you very much!